# get first value of a dot separated string (Bash)

Tags: linux, string, bash, shell, bioinformatics

Hey so I have a string in bash named

`chicken.fasta.count.sorted.topthree.txt` It's a string delimited by dots and I want the value before the first dot.

I just want the substring 'chicken' and I want to store it in a variable.

Can someone show me the way?

```
s="$chicken.fasta.count.sorted.topthree.txt"
animal_name="${s%.*}
```

Comment: See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).

Comment: Use `${s%%.*}` instead of `${s%.*}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using [cut](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) command:

`echo "chicken.fasta.count.sorted.topthree.txt | cut -d '.' -f 1`

Answer (score 0):

Use either of these Perl one-liners:

```
echo 'chicken.fasta.count.sorted.topthree.txt' | perl -lne 'print /([^.]*)/'
```

or

```
echo 'chicken.fasta.count.sorted.topthree.txt' | perl -F'[.]' -lane 'print $F[0]'
```

`/([^.]*)/` : match the pattern that has any non-dot character (`[^.]`) repeated 0 or more times (`*`). The pattern is captured with parentheses and pass to `print`, which prints it.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-F'[.]'` : Split into `@F` on a literal dot (`.`), rather than on whitespace.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)